# iOS 5 segue implementation

Tags: storyboard, ios5

While implementing a segue between two view controllers how to change a property of the destination view controller using the segue object? The documentation says that this can be done inside the prepareForSegue: sender: method. i tried it but not was not successful

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if you still need an answer to this, but it was such a lonely post, and if I'm correct, this doesn't fall under NDA any longer. If I'm mistaken, please moderate my answer into oblivion, so here we go: I just finished doing something that uses what you need. This is code that works for me:

```c
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"relevantSegueIdentifier"])
    {
        // [segue destinationViewController] is read-only, so in order to
        // write to that view controller you'll have to locally instantiate
        // it here:
        ViewController *upcomingViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        
        // You now have a solid reference to the upcoming / destination view
        // controller. Example use: Allocate and initialize some property of
        // the destination view controller before you reach it and inject a
        // reference to the current view controller into the upcoming one:
        upcomingViewController.someProperty = [[SomePropertyClass alloc] initWithString:@"Whatever!"];
        upcomingViewController.initialViewController = [segue sourceViewController];
        // Or, equivalent, but more straightforward:
        //upcomingViewController.initialViewController = self;
    }
}
```

This assumes that both someProperty and initialViewController are synthesized accessors of the destination view controller. Hope this helps!

Comment: it falls under NDA but in 3 days it won't the official release is on the 14th of october, but i like ur answer +1

Comment: I tried what you say but the properties on my `destinationViewController` don't updates. Any advice?

Comment: I take it you use a synthesized accessor (not a private ivar) of the destination view controller and that the view controller is already instantiated during app setup (i.e. storyboard with actual view controllers placed in it, a segue between them all instantiated @ app launch). In that case, it should work. It could then be something like the system not knowing about your specific dest. view controller class. The class ViewController in my example is a subclass of UIViewController, and before @implementation I do something like '#import "ViewController.h"'. Could it be one of these things?

Answer (score 5):

I have written a tutorial that gives code examples for passing information to the new scene and information back from a scene using delegation so check it out it should solve your problem. [iOS 5 Storyboard: How To use Segues, Scenes and Static Content UITableViews](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219)

Comment: I read the blog before hitting this post.. thanks for the blog.

Answer (score 0):

What I use in source view controller is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *upcomingViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    upcomingViewController.view.tag = [[segue identifier] hash];
}
```

And then in the destination view controller I use (use for instance in the viewDidAppear)

```
if(self.view.tag == [@"MySeqgueIdentifier" hash])
{
   // Do something here...
}
```

This is cool, since you don't have to create any properties etc. and everything works right from interface builder.