# use prepareForSegue for button

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

Hi I create button programmatically and I connect my button to another view, but I got segue problem 
that I should use prepareForSegue method for storyboard but I don't know how there ar esome sample to the internet but I will get error when I used that sample, would you please help me

Thanks in advance!

here is my code

**Creating Button**

```
 UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed: 201.0/255.0 green: 201.0/255.0 blue:201.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
        button.tag = currentTag;
        currentTag++;
        [button.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [button.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentTag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(80*x, 32*y, 80, 32); 
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonView addSubview: button];
```

**Action for button**

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
NSLog(@"button %u -- frame: %@", button.tag, NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
WeekView *crtObj=[[WeekView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WeekView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:crtObj animated:YES];
[crtObj release];


}
```

**Prepare for segue**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"WeekView"]) {

        // Get reference to the destination view controller
       WeekView *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];  //// I don't know what should I write instead of object
    }}
```

**error**

[image]

**Edit 2:**** I have a warning :**

**Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier for use with -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"WeekView"]) {

        // Get reference to the destination view controller
     //  WeekView *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
       // [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"WeekView"];
    }}
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595374/ios-5-segue-implementation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are really two ways to push a view controller onto the navigation controller.

1. The old way, all in code. That is what you did. You can completely forget about segues at this point.
2. The new way: establish a Segue in Storyboard (push segue from one view controller to a new view controller, which you also define in Storyboard), give it an `Identifier` name and then use this code to push the view controller.

.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:myIdentifyer sender:self];
```

where self is the view controller. Now you can do the customizations in `prepareForSegue:`.

Answer (score 4):

the sample code in this case is just telling you the type of thing you can do in `prepareForSegue:sender:` .

it is suggesting that the viewController to which you are attempting to segue would have a method `setMyObjectHere:` and it would be expecting you to pass that object.

as an example, your class might have a `setTitle:` method, and in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` code, you could pre-set the title based on information in the controller you are performing the segue from.

to get rid of the warning, you need an identifier, as in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: added a picture to show you where to add the id to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

"The old way to code", no the better way to code hopefully this helps, but if your using UIButtons and UIViews programmatically  you shouldn't even be using segues.

Create a root view control in app delegate, than just pop on and off the next viewcontrollers and such.

For example this is all you need in your viewcontrollers:

```
-(void)nextControllerButton:(UIButton*)button{

    SearchViewController *nextController = [[SearchViewController alloc] init];

    nextController.username = _username.text;
    nextController.password = _password.text;

    [self.navigationController showViewController:nextController sender:self];
}
```